# Rashi quoting Yerushalmi on Kodshim

Tags: rashi, talmud-yerushalmi, kodshim, maseches-temura

I haven't learned *Seder Kodshim* before, and I understand there's no Talmud Yerushalmi on *Seder Kodshim*, but I saw in a bunch of places in *maseches Temurah* where Rashi quotes "*loshon Yerushalmi*" (search לשון ירושלמי on Sefaria, turned up ten instances in Temurah). It's always a different version of the *gemarra* than what appears in the *Bavli*.

Is this referring to the Talmud Yerushalmi? How did Rashi have a Yerushalmi on *Kodshim*, and we don't? Or is it just a different *girsa* in the *Bavli* that originated from Jerusalem? Or something else?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Melechet_Shlomo_on_Mishnah_Temurah.3.3.3

Comment: From what I recall reading, it's accepted that there was at some point a (legitimate) Yerushalmi Kodshim, but it was lost at some point. Many Rishonim apparently quote/reference it.

Comment: @Salmon there is a theory like that but it's hardly accepted

Comment: [Prof. Epstein](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/epstein-jacob-nahum) explains in ‘ML Ha’amoraim’ ([p. 137](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40975&st=&pgnum=133&hilite=)) that this was a later Jeru. recension of Tem. which retained stylistic differences than others. His student, [Eliezer S. Rosenthal](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/אליעזר_שמשון_רוזנטל), agrees with him (save for a reading in Shitah Mekubezet which might corroborate the general theory; cf. Rosenthal [p. 320](http://daf-yomi.com/Data/UploadedFiles/Forums/17914.pdf)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Artscroll [Teumrah 6b footnote 12 the last paragraph] quotes a Doros HaRishonim who conjectures, that ..

> "in the case of Temurah, there existed two types of manuscripts, those
>   that originated from Babylonia and those that originated from Eretz
>   Yisroel. Not knowing which was the authentic version, scribes who
>   encountered two versions recorded both, and labeled one לישנא אחרינא,
>   another version. Rashi [[on
>   6b](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Temurah.6b.6.2)] states that
>   there is no substantive difference between the two versions (in that
>   particular gemara). It is just that one originated from Eretz Yisroel
>   manuscript ("Yerushalmi") and the other from Babylonian manuscript
>   ("Bavli")."

Comment: I'd have to see the Doros HaRishonim inside, but Rashi to Temurah 6b isn't conclusive. He just says this *loshon* is Yerushalmi and this *loshon* is Bavli; no indication of their essence

Comment: @robev - I don't have access to Doros HaRishonim Vol. 6 right now, but if I get it I"ll try to  post a copy.

Comment: Interesting that Artscroll would quote Weiss in DH instead of the more “accepted” Maharaz Chajes who says the same ([§2, left column](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1023&st=&pgnum=287)).

Comment: @Oliver, דורות הראשונים isn't from Weiss, but from R. Isaac Halevi. The link is http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=20282#p=54.

Comment: @Meir Correct, I hastily misspoke. HaLevi’s opinion is also discussed by Rosenthal which I [cited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106132/rashi-quoting-yerushalmi-on-kodshim#comment355558_106132).